# Middleware JavaScript not recognized

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, passport-local

I've recently started learning on my own and I am stuck at this and can't get past it.

I'm trying to create a login page and for the first time I'm using middleware

I'm getting an error:     throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

This is the code down below:

```
var express               = require("express"),
    mongoose              = require("mongoose"),
    passport              = require("passport"),
    bodyParser            = require("body-parser"),
    User                  =require("./models/user"),
    LocalStrategy         =require("passport-local"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/auth_demo_app", { useUnifiedTopology: true },{ useNewUrlParser: true });
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "Neno is the best and cutest dog in the world.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); // Encoding the session
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser()); // Decoding the session

// =========
// ROUTES 
// =========

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});
app.get("/secret", function(req, res){
    res.render("secret");
});

// ===========
// Auth ROUTES
// ===========

// Show Signup Form
app.get("/register", function (req, res){ // req - request / res - response
    res.render("register");
});
//handling USER SIGN UP
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    req.body.username
    req.body.password
    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.render("register");
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                res.redirect("secret");
            })
        }
    });
})

//handling USER LOG IN / LOGIN ROUTES

app.get("/login", function (req, res){
    res.render("login");
});
//login logic
//middleware
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/secret",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}),function(req, res) {
});
app.listen(3000, function (){
    console.log("Server Started......");
})
```

Comment: Which of the five invocations of `app.use` is failing? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass strategy to passport, not to the app.

Replace

```
app.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

With

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

Also I think you need to pass a function `new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate)` instead of it's result. Unless of course you have implemented it to return a callback (hard to say w/o seeing your code)

Comment: Helol Yury,
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

Thank you very much it works now :)